# Interpretation of IMF Balance of Payments Data - Financial Account

Tags: balance-of-payments

While I understand the meaning of the components of the Financial account what I don't understand is the concept of "assets" and "liabilities" after direct investment, portfolio investment etc.

A lot of studies have looked at gross capital inflows, gross capital outflows and net capital flows but don't mention exactly the procedure to find these.

I would really appreciate if anyone can explain.

[image]

Comment: From the varying signs, these look like flows.  So "direct investments, assets" are US residents and companies  making direct investments abroad (including retained earnings of existing subsidiaries abroad) and "direct investments, liabilities" are foreigners doing the same in the US.  Portfolio investment involves purchases of stocks and bonds, while other investment includes loans and bank deposits

Comment: Is it correct to then consider assets as outflows and liabilities as inflows to the U.S?

Comment: Increases in assets might be thought of as if they are balancing exports of goods and services (similarly increases in liabilities and imports).  So in that sense, yes.  Many people regard inward investment (i.e. an  increase in liabilities) as an inflow.